# How can I install insulation batts between joists with variable spacing?

Tags: insulation, attic

I am trying to put insulation above a garage but the problem is the space in between the cross beams are different. They varying between 16", 17", 18". What would be the best way to insulate this space using batt without using blow-in insulation?

I have only found widths of 16" and 15" using R30 for attics.

[image]

Comment: You could cut it strips of 16", 17"or 18" to make it fit, but that would be a heck of job. Probably the way with the least amount of material wasted though. So if time is no constraint this might be your option.

Comment: Blown in cellulose is the right answer, even though it's not what you want to do. :-)

Comment: can't do blown in because I have a mini-split. The cellulose will get into the unit.

Comment: @amrog it looks like you had blown in previously. One simple solution would be to lay down an air barrier before blowing in the insulation. That should prevent insulation from being sucked into the mini split unit.

Comment: @RibaldEddie, what do you mean by an air barrier?

Comment: @amrog is the attic conditioned space? But what I mean is something like 6mil poly sheeting or some other form of barrier, like tyvek, that would prevent air mixing from the attic to down below. In most construction I would expect to see a vapor barrier on the bottom of the ceiling joists between the drywall and the joists.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to cut the bats into 16-18" lengths (depending on the width of the specific joist cavity you're trying to fill) and run them crosswise in the joist cavities.  You'll then end up with a quite a few pieces to fit in, but they'll all fit your different widths as you cut them to length to fit.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find 23" batts for use in 24" OC framing, and then you would cut them down to fit.

But that would result in a lot of cutting, I would rather just blow insulation in.

Comment: does it matter faced or unfaced in an open space above the garage?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I would go with unfaced.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions;

Use polyester batts which can be ripped quickly leaving a straight edge.

Or

Place batts at right angles over the joists, capturing an extra air pocket underneath. Much better insulation. Local code may require some indicator pegs (drywall) sticking up to mark where the joists are.

Answer (score 0):

We cut bats to fit.

Either a thin sliver to fill the edge, or cut the bats such one half fits and the other needs a sliver.